# The true meaning of お陰様で

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

In the past (or even today) were there certain people who, when saying お陰様で, actually believed and meant that their state of well-being was in fact due to people (or beings, whether they be supernatural or not), working surreptitiously behind-the-scenes (in "the shadows" so to speak), unbeknownst to them?

Answer (score 1):

At least in postwar Japan, this is a common set phrase that does not necessarily assume the presence of a specific human or deity working behind-the-scenes. In other words, it can be used like either "thanks to X" (with a specific X as a supporter in mind) or just unspecific "thankfully". There is no religious significance at all at least in modern Japanese.

Etymologically, [お陰](https://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%8A%E8%94%AD) has something to do with religious beliefs, so some people in the past may have used this in connection with religion.